# Classic ASP, form subbmitting to page 403.0 - Not Allowed only on iOS Safari

Tags: asp-classic, mobile-safari, http-status-code-403

Recently I started getting an error on Classic ASP pages (yeah, I know) when submitting a form on index.asp to verify.asp.  When verify loads I get a 403.0 Not Allowed error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

The kicker is this only happens in iOS Safari.  Doesn't happen in any other browser or on desktops.  It started back in May of this year.

- Windows Server 2016
- Microsoft Azure
- Classic ASP - everything else works on the site in iOS
- Require SSL is not checked
- SSL Certificates are installed and test just fine

I have even removed everything from the verify.asp page and just have "Hello World" in the HTML code.  Same issue.

Comment: Are there any session variables involved? I believe that Safari has a problem storing them

Comment: Not on this form, no.  Elsewhere there are, on the site.  But not having any issues except for something wonky with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just stumbled upon the answer.
on my index.asp page, this was the FORM tag:

```
<form action="verify.asp" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```

I checked the IIS log and found the sub-code.  403.14 - Directory listing denied.
I have directory listing turned off.  Previously just providing the page, if within the same directory as the form, it would work.  Apparently not anymore.

I updated the tag to this:

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/foldername/verify.asp" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```

...and it worked.  WTF Safari.

Comment: Wouldn’t `/foldername/verify.asp` work instead of providing an absolute url?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, didn't work.  However, I did notice that someone on my IT team enabled a URL Rewrite rule to force back to an HTTPS if the visitor was on HTTP.  I disabled this rule and everything worked just fine.